# No puedo pasar parametros por get desde url

Tags: php

Tengo un form donde muestro la caja grande, es un resumen de cada vez que se cerro la caja chica del dia digamos.
Y en una columna un boton de detalle donde redirijo al detalle de ventas de ese dia y cajero:

index.php?controller=caja&action=detalles&id=76&idc=21&nombre=ELI19

El caso es que quiero obtener esos 3 parametros con get para mandarlos a un archivo de impresion pero no los toma: sale el pdf vacio y en la consola del navegador los valores estan vacios:

el detalle de la caja grande lo armo con ajax:

```js
accion="cajagrande";
  $.ajax({
   
            type: "POST",
            url: "/views/modules/caja/procesocaja.php",
            data: { "accion": accion}, 
            dataType: "json",
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
            },
            success: function(filtrado){
               
           console.log(filtrado);
           subtotal=0;
               for (var i = 0; i < filtrado.length; i++) {
                    if (filtrado[i].tipomov=="e"){
                        var t="entrada";
                        subtotal=parseFloat(subtotal)+parseFloat(filtrado[i].monto);
                    }else{
                        var t="salida";
                        subtotal=parseFloat(subtotal) - parseFloat(filtrado[i].monto);
                    }
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                 
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].fecha + "</td>" +
"<td>" + filtrado[i].nombre + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + t + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + filtrado[i].monto + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + subtotal + "</td>" +
                 "<td><a class='btn btn-warning' href='index.php?controller=caja&action=detalles&id="+filtrado[i].idsesion+"&idc="+filtrado[i].iduser+"&nombre="+filtrado[i].nombre+"'>Detalle</a></td>" +
            
            
                 "</tr>";
               $(newRow).appendTo("#detallegrande tbody");                
        
    
               
            }
```

Entonces dentro de un detalle de caja chica hago:

```html
<form method="GET" action="views/modules/caja/reportecajas.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php $_GET['id'] ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="idc" value="<?php $_GET['idc']?>" />
  <input type="hidden" name="nombre" value="<?php $_GET['nombre']?>" />
```

Obtengo lo siguiente en la consola:

**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-download: "http://ottracerveza.com/views/modules/caja/reportecajas.php?id=&idc=&nombre=".**

Comment: Si vas a mandar parámetros por URL entonces debes hacer uso de `GET` y no de `POST`

Comment: Igual no lo toma..ahi modifique la pregunta, el boton detalle de caja chica lo armo con jquery y llega bien

Comment: Ahi encontre otro error pero no se a que se debe